# keyevent android phone locked

Tags: android, keyevent, locked

I´m new to android development and I´m trying to make an app.
What I want to know is if is it possible to get key events even when the phone is locked?

For example to make my music player change the music when I press the `DPAD_CENTER_BUTTON`

Doing something like this:

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
        {
            //your Action code
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you found a reliable solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a broadcast receiver for the Intent Filter `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`